# how to use xlsx files as dataset into scikit-learn for supervised learning

Tags: scikit-learn, supervised-learning

I am having 2 xlsx files and I want to use that as datasets in sklearn classifier for implementing different machine learning algorithms. I'm a newbie please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [pandas module](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html) for reading Excel files into DataFrame's:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/file1.xlsx')
df2 = pd.read_excel(r'/path/to/file2.xlsx')
```